# why "{}".format(1241.123124) is different from "{:g}".format(1241.123124)

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
>>> "{}".format(1241.123124)
'1241.123124'
>>> "{:g}".format(1241.123124)
'1241.12'
```

In the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

It says

> None The same as 'g'.

Comment: Which python version are you running?

Comment: It is also mentioned "The default precision is 6."

Comment: Precision means different things for the `f` and `g` specifiers; that would be the explanation if `{}` was equivalent to `{:f}`, which contradicts what the documentation says.

Comment: @Tichodroma No, it's not clear what Python version OP is running, regardless of which docs version they quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a documentation error. There is an [open bug report on the Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue21195). Let's hope it gets addressed:

> The documentation for a None (empty) format for floats indicates that
>   it is equivalent to the g format. This does not appear to be correct
>   ([Precise definition of float string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525924/precise-definition-of-float-string-formatting)).
>
> The Python 3.4 documentation
>   (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)
>   seems to be much closer to what Python 2.7 does.
>
> It would be useful to have a more correct documentation for the effect
>   of a None format for floats in Python 2.7 (maybe by copying the Python
>   3.4 documentation if it applies).

Comment: I believe that this bug is where the error came from: http://bugs.python.org/issue5920